# Transform an input of reactive Form with CurrencyPipe

Tags: angular, regex, angular-reactive-forms, currency-pipe

I have an input where I need to type a monetary value. This means I need to input a comma "," (EUR).
I following Code works fine, but the comma is being ignored, I tried out different expressions but no one is working fine.
How can I also allow commas?

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addTicketForm.valueChanges.subscribe((form) => {
      if (form.ek) {
        this.addTicketForm.patchValue(
          {
            ek: this.currencyPipe.transform(
              form.ek.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0+/, ''),
              'EUR',
              'symbol',
              '1.0-0',
              'de'
            ),
          },
          { emitEvent: false }
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

```
<div class="form-group col-3">
        <label for="ek">EK</label>
        <input id="ek" class="form-control" formControlName="ek" />
      </div>
```

Comment: Do you need to have the comma on the form? That's usually a bad idea, for monetary values you should store only the number and use a pipe to show it formatted. You can use the default currency pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Comment: `/\D/` matches (and removes) all non-digits. Try `/[^0-9,]/` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have integer values with no fractional parts, instead of `form.ek.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0+/, '')`, you can use

```js
Number(ek.replace(/\D+/g, '')).toLocaleString('en')
```

That is

- Remove all non-digit chars (including commas, dots, etc.) with `.replace(/\D+/g, '')`
- Format the number using `Number(...).toLocaleString('en')`.